# Difference of polylogarithms of complex conjugate arguments

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, zeta-functions, polylogarithm

I have the expression

$$\tag{1}
\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(z)-\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(z^*)
$$

Where $\operatorname{Li}$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) and $^*$ denotes complex conjugation. The expression is *similar* to

$$
\operatorname{Li}_{s}(e^{2\pi ia})+e^{i\pi s}\operatorname{Li}_{s}(e^{-2\pi ia})=\frac{(2\pi)^s}{\Gamma(s)}e^{i\pi s/2}\zeta(1-s,a)
$$

from [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#ii), where $\zeta$ is the [Hurwitz zeta](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11) function. This makes me wonder if a similar compact representation of (1) exists. The duplication and inversion formulas are also *almost* applicable, but not quite (or, so it seems to me).

For context, (1) results from performing the sum

$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2}e^{-an}\sin(bn)
$$

Comment: Interesting problem. What is nice is the contour plot and the 3D plot of the summation